# Can a Tab Layout like this be implemented?

Tags: android, xml

Tab Layout: selected tab gets hilighted insted of getting underline

[image: Tab Layout: selected tab gets hilighted insted of getting underline]

Comment: `Can ...` **Yes**.

Comment: either you custom your own or using this lib https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

Answer (score 0):

A tab layout like in the image can certainly be created. But google has already specified a set of components to use in line with the material design. It is always best to follow such practices when developing apps to give the user a better and uniform feel of the platform. So I would suggest you please use the material tabs specified by google. Please find more detail at https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html